# Python: Changing precedence of import file types (.py before .so)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-importlib

If I do `import A` from within a directory containing both `A.py` and `A.so`, the `.so` file will be imported. I'm interested in changing the order of import file types, so that `.py` takes precedence over `.so`, though only temporarily, i.e. between code line `i` and `j`. Surely this can be achieved through *some* [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) magic?

Currently I get around the issue by copying the `.py` into a separate directory, prepending this directory to `sys.path` and *then* do the import, which is just awful.

#### Why the need?

The `.so` file(s) are cython-compiled versions of the `.py` files. I'm doing some custom code transformation on top of cython, for which I need to import the `.py` source even when the "equivalent" `.so` is present.

#### Test setup

Here follows a simple test setup.

```py
# A.py
import B
```

```py
# B.py
import C
print('hello from B')
```

```py
# C.py
pass
```

Running `python A.py` successfully prints out the message from `B.py`. Now add `B.so` (as the content of the `.so` files is irrelevant, having `B.so` really be a text file is fine):

```
# B.so
this is a fake binary
```

Now `python A.py` fails. Though [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) is the modern way of doing things, I so far only know how to import a specific file directly using the deprecated [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) module. Updating `A.py` to

```py
# A.py
import imp
B = imp.load_source('B', 'B.py')
```

makes it work again. However, introducing `C.so` breaks it again, as the lookup for the `.py` rather than `.so` is not registered globally in the import mechanism:

```
# C.so
this is a fake binary
```

Note that in this example I'm only allowed to edit `A.py`. I'm in need of a solution for Python 3.8, but I suspect any solution for 3.x works on 3.8 as well.

Comment: "*though only temporarily, i.e. between code line i and j*": wouldn;t that make the whole thing pointless since once a module was imported it won't be re imported?

Comment: @CristiFati No, that's what I need. I load the module within a function, do stuff, and return from the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now have a working solution. It's somewhat hacky, but I think it's robust.

It turns out that `sys.path_importer_cache` store various *finders* which in turn store a `list` of *loaders*, which are quarried by `import` in order. These loaders are stored as 2-tuples, with the first element exactly being the file extension which the given loader handles.

I simply traverse all `list`'s of loaders and push those with `.so` extension to the back of the `list`'s, achieving the lowest precedence possible (I could remove them completely, but then I can't import *any* `.so` files). I keep track of the changes to `sys.path_importer_cache` and undo them once I'm done with my special import. All of this is neatly wrapped up in a context manager:

```py
import collections, contextlib, sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def disable_loader(ext):
    ext = '.' + ext.lstrip('.')
    # Push any loaders for the ext extension to the back
    edits = collections.defaultdict(list)
    path_importer_cache = list(sys.path_importer_cache.values())
    for i, finder in enumerate(path_importer_cache):
        loaders = getattr(finder, '_loaders', None)
        if loaders is None:
            continue
        for j, loader in enumerate(loaders):
            if j + len(edits[i]) == len(loaders):
                break
            if loader[0] != ext:
                continue
            # Loader for the ext extension found.
            # Push to the back.
            loaders.append(loaders.pop(j))
            edits[i].append(j)
    try:
        # Yield control back to the caller
        yield
    finally:
        # Undo changes to path importer cache
        for i, edit in edits.items():
            loaders = path_importer_cache[i]._loaders
            for j in reversed(edit):
                loaders.insert(j, loaders.pop())

# Demonstrate import failure
try:
    import A
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Demonstrate solution
with disable_loader('.so'):
    import A

# Demonstrate (wanted) failure outside with statement
import A2
```

Note that for the `import A2` to fail properly, you need to copy the test setup so that you also have `A2.py`, `B2.py`, `C2.py`, `B2.so` and `C2.so`, which import each other in the same way as the original test files.

One can get rid of the somewhat complicated bookkeeping involving `edits` by just taking a complete backup `copy.deepcopy(sys.path_importer_cache)` before making the changes, and sticking this backup onto `sys` once done. It does work in the limited test above, but as various parts of the import machinery might hold references to the different nested objects, I thought it safer to use mutation only.

Comment: python imports .so file first by default?

Comment: @datdinhquoc yes, they even have priority over `.py`.